# 5.0 Juno - There is no display on videos

Tags: display, graphic-drivers, release-juno

I just start using elementary os 5.0 juno today and after installiation, system showed update notifications. After 13 programs updated, i opened a video and there is no display but video continued and there is sound. I tried different programs after that, same result. What should i do now? I can play videos from youtube. But i can not play files .mkv .mp4 etc.

Could it be a problem of Nvidia video card?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When i am looking for nvidia x server setting, i saw two GPU modes on PRIME Profiles: NVIDIA (Perfomance mode) and Intel (Power Saving Mode). I choose Intel Power Saving Mode and loged off. After i log in back, videos were working okay.